# Connectify-like functionality on Intel 4965 AGN wireless?

Tags: networking, wireless, intel, wireless-access-point

I would like to use my laptop as an Access point, so that i can connect my phones through Wifi. I have done this my office laptop T410. I am having T61 with wifi module 4965. Connectify on windows does not support it. I am following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint) 
to make achieve WAP capability on my T61 running ubuntu 10.10.

The link says something about "master mode", how do i put my T61 wifi-inter4965 in master mode. Can I install madwifi or atheros drivers on it? I am using galaxy S froyo, and it does not support Ad-hoc network. Has anyone tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the current driver for the Intel 4965 Wireless card does not support Master (AP) mode,
http://bugzilla.intellinuxwireless.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1585

However, [it appears there is work on this](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg54806.html). It is an issue of the Linux kernel (where the driver is now developed) to get support for AP Mode.

As a workaround for now you could get an inexpensive USB Wireless dongle that does support AP Mode. They cost between $10-$20.